# How can I pass form data to another form with no action in form tag?

Tags: php, forms, email

I understand how to pass form data from one form to the other when using an action in the form tag, but I'm not using this, because I want to perform some PHP on the first page with the initial form.

Once this code has been executed, then I'd like to redirect to the next form, and pass through the values entered. I managed to do this before I added the PHP code by using `$_REQUEST` on the second form, and by setting the action of the first form, to be the second form page.

Can this still be done when the action is removed from the first form?

**Action when submit button is clicked**

```
// Send email if Book Enquiry form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['bookEnquiry'])) {
$to      = 'local@localhost.local';
$subject = 'Enquiry Interest from BellaVou';
$firstname = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : '';
$surname = isset($_POST['surname']) ? $_POST['surname'] : '';
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$message = $firstname.' '.$surname.' ('.$email.') has just submitted the initial enquiry form.';
$headers = 'From: local@localhost.local' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
wp_safe_redirect('/contact-us/enquiry-form');
}
```

**Form on first page**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="firstname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">First Name</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname" required />
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="surname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Surname</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" id="surname" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required />
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="bookEnquiry">Continue</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You should create a session variable before redirect and then get the session values on next page.

Comment: Simplest option is to just put the email sending php code at the top of the second form. Then you can continue to use the posted data as you where

Comment: @Steve that's a great idea that I can't believe I didn't think of. This is definitely the way I'm going to go. I think it would be best to wrap the mail function in an IF, to check if the initial fields are not empty, otherwise the email will be sent even if just visiting the second page.

Comment: @Lee yes data validation is important, but note that the existing `if(isset($_POST[...]))` check would fail on a page visit, as that would be a get request. Glad i could help

Comment: @Steve do you want to add your suggestion as an answer, and I'll mark it as correct? Thanks for your help!